# How to change pop up background color on IE9

Tags: background, popup, internet-explorer-9

IE9 pop up windows has black background color when showing PNG image. I found a workaround which works on Firefox 10 (and above) that also shows PNG with dark background on pop up window. Here is the code, this doesn't work for IE9:

```
function openLarge() {
    var image = $('main-image').href;
    NewWin = window.open(image,"LargeImage","resizable=yes,scrollbars=auto,status=no,width=710,height=510");
    NewWin.document.writeln("<body bgcolor='#fff'>");
    NewWin.document.writeln("<img src='" + image + "'>");
    NewWin.document.writeln("<\/body>");
    NewWin.document.close();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try to change `<body bgcolor='#fff'>` to `<body style='background:#fff'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is with the opening address. If you remove the `image` reference, and open up to a blank document, you'll have your background set.

I suspect this has something to do with the headers upon first loading the resource. With an image, the content type would be set to `image/jpeg` or something, but then we're attempting to manipulate the document as if it were `text/html`.

```
function openLarge() {
    var image = $('main-image').href;
    NewWin = window.open('',"LargeImage","resizable=yes,scrollbars=auto,status=no,width=710,height=510");
    NewWin.document.writeln("<body bgcolor='#fff'>");
    NewWin.document.writeln("<img src='" + image + "'>");
    NewWin.document.writeln("<\/body>");
    NewWin.document.close();
}
```